# Notification Hub Rest API - The specified resource description is invalid

Tags: c#, azure, xmldocument, dotnet-httpclient, azure-notificationhub

Okay, so when i'm trying to do a create registration call to the rest api I get the error "The specified resource description is invalid".

I assume something is wrong with the xml body but when testing with postman it works so I am probably doing something wrong with the loadXml or the sendAsync??

This is the code i'm using.

```
 client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://myservicehub.servicebus.windows.net");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-version", "2015-01");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", sasToken);
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "/myservicehub/registrations/?api-version=2015-01");

             XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

             doc.LoadXml("<entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'>" +
                 "<content type='application/xml'>"+
                 "<AppleRegistrationDescription xmlns:i='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/netservices/2010/10/servicebus/connect'>"+
                 "<Tags>user</Tags>"+
                 "<DeviceToken>EEEEEE</DeviceToken>" +
                 "</AppleRegistrationDescription>"+
                 "</content>"+
                 "</entry>");

            request.Content = new StringContent(doc.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/atom+xml");

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
```

request in postman

```
PostUrl:https://myservicehub.servicebus.windows.net/myservicehub/registrations/?api-version=2015-01



 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'>
    <content type='application/xml'>
        <AppleRegistrationDescription xmlns:i='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/netservices/2010/10/servicebus/connect'>
            <Tags>user</Tags>
            <DeviceToken>EEEEEE</DeviceToken>
        </AppleRegistrationDescription>
    </content>
</entry>
```

So what am I doing wrong ?

Best,
Robin

Comment: Could you update the question with the URL and the body of the request that works in Postman?

Comment: updated now @NikitaG.

Comment: Can you compare requests and responses from Postman and your application using Fiddler http://www.telerik.com/fiddler?

Comment: Installed fiddler and my textview/syntaxview now has this "System.Xml.XmlDocument" So im guessing its not sending the xml correctly? @DmitryP.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it thanks to Dmitry P. The problem was at this row

```
 request.Content = new StringContent(doc.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/atom+xml");
```

changed it to:

```
 request.Content = new StringContent(doc.OuterXml, Encoding.UTF8, "application/atom+xml");
```

Comment: Why do you need to first load XML and then convert it to string at all? Just pass the XML string into StringContent object directly.